# Gap between "fibration" and "fiber bundle".

Tags: homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, fibration

There are fibrations $E \rightarrow B$ which are not fiber bundles. Example: $E = [0,1]^2 / \text{middle vertical line segment}$ and $B=[0,1]$.

In this example, $E$ has the homotopy type of a total space in a fiber bundle over $B$: namely $E'=[0,1]^2$. Is this always true?

If you don't know, then still I would appreciate any new examples of fibrations that aren't fiber bundles.

Comment: Some time ago, I asked a topologist the same question.. The answer was "Fibration is a categorical notion, so it depends on the category of spaces you consider. For a nice category like CW-complexes it's probably true, but for too general spaces/maps it's probably false", but he had no counterexample either. I'd really like to see one too.

Comment: @Ben, i want to see the proof in $CW$-case more than counterexample in general. (I had some ideas to prove, but they failed)

Comment: also i had an answer that "Fibration arise in homotopic problems, and fiber bundles in geometric ones; so these are two different instruments to work with, and connection between them is useless and non-interesting," -- here i'm not agree with the last statement.

Comment: Dear @AndreyRyabichev, I don't know how it works for sure either, but maybe it's time to reconsider the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news as long as we only care for CW complexes. In D. Barnes, *The simplicial bundle of a CW Fibration* ([jstor link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2046409)), to every fibration with base and fibres being CW, there is associated a fibre-homotopic (simplicial) fibre bundle.

Answer (score 6):

If the fibration is smooth and the spaces involved are compact, then it is a fiber bundle. Just to make clear what I mean by smooth fibration:

**Definition.** A smooth map $p\colon E \to B$ is said to satisfy the homotopy lifting property in the smooth category if given the following commutative diagram where all maps are smooth:

[image]

there exists an smooth map $\widetilde{F}$ making the following diagram smooth:

[image]

**Definition.** A smooth map is said to be a smooth (Hurewicz) fibration if it satisfies the homotopy lifting property in the smooth category for all manifolds $Y$.

**Definition.** A smooth map is said to be a smooth Serre fibration if it satisfies the homotopy lifting property in the smooth category for all discs $I^n$, $n\ge 0$.

Now the **idea of the proof**:

1) A (Serre) fibration $p\colon E \to B$ where $B$ is path-connected and $E\neq \emptyset$ is surjective.

2) A smooth (Serre) fibration is a submersion. I asked the question and it was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290610/smooth-fibration-is-a-submersion/2290761#2290761).

3) Compactness combined with the above guarantees we can apply [Ehresmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_lemma) and we are done.

**Remark.**  This works for weak or Serre fibrations. You don't need to assume you are working with Hurewicz fibrations. So the answer is a bit more general than the question you asked.