# Smooth fibration is a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)) and the following questions: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415356/when-is-a-fibration-a-fiber-bundle), [[2]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116231/given-a-serre-fibration-between-manifolds-how-ugly-can-it-be) or their respective answers or comments it is said that a smooth fibration is a submersion. To make clear what I mean:

**Definition.** A smooth map $p\colon E \to B$ is said to satisfy the homotopy lifting property in the smooth category if given the following commutative diagram where all maps are smooth:

[image]

there exists an smooth map $\widetilde{F}$ making the following diagram smooth:

[image]

**Definition.** A smooth map is said to be a smooth (Hurewicz) fibration if it satisfies the homotopy lifting property in the smooth category for all manifolds $Y$.

**Definition.** A smooth map is said to be a smooth Serre fibration if it satisfies the homotopy lifting property in the smooth category for all discs $I^n$, $n\ge 0$.

**Question.** Could you please help me to understand why smooth Serre fibrations or smooth Hurewicz fibrations are submersions.

I have tried using the characteristic property of submersions and so on.....but I haven't been able to prove anything.

By the way, I know that the projections in smooth fiber bundles are smooth submersions. That is straightforward. But I would like to generalize it to fibrations.

**Remark.** If necessary we can assume both $B$ and $E$ are compact since it is the case I am interested in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x$ be a point of $B$, consider a chart $f:U\simeq I^n\rightarrow B$ whose domain contains $x$ and $f(0)=x$. Write $Y=\{x\}$ and consider a point $z\in p^{-1}(x)$. You can define $\tilde f:Y\times \{0\}\rightarrow E$ by $\tilde f(x,0)=z$.
Let $F:\{x\}\times I^n\rightarrow B$ defined by $F(x,y)=f(x)$. We have $p\circ \tilde f=F\circ i$. The homotopy lifting property implies the existence of $H:\{x\}\times U\rightarrow E$ such that $p\circ H=f$. Since the tangent map $df_0:T_0\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow T_xB$ is bijective, and $df_0=dp_z\circ dH_{(0,x)}$, we deduce that $dp_z$ is surjective, and henceforth $p$ is a submersion.

Comment: Let me just point out that this proof will definitely fail for the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @David Roberts: Many things fail in the infinite dimensional case. Or rather they tend to ramify. Typically unless people say otherwise its supposed that the finite dimensional case is meant.